# Setting PHP variables from Database Using MYSQL

Tags: php, variables, select, mysqli, fetch

Looking to select multiple values from the database and echo with PHP.  (Newbie)

For instance:

```
SELECT sponser, contract, script FROM Copy WHERE day = '11092014' and time = 4
SELECT sponser, contract, script FROM Copy WHERE day = '11092014' and time = 5
SELECT sponser, contract, script FROM Copy WHERE day = '11092014' and time = 6
```

How would I set the variables.. something along the lines of this using MYSQLi for multiple variables?

```
$sqlStremail = "SELECT subcheckr
                FROM login 
                WHERE username = '$u'";

$result = mysql_query($query);

$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);

$variable = $row["subcheckr"];
```

Truly appreciate any help.

Comment: Please avoid using mysql use pdo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. Though if your query returns multiple rows, you'll need to use:

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
{
//do something here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to make a loop for , foreach or a while loop

ex

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
{

}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do it. First you need to connect, then you build your query. If query fails display an error so you know what went wrong. Then build your data array and use it.

```
$db = mysql_connect("localhost", "mysql_user", "mysql_password");
$sqlStremail = "SELECT `subcheckr`
                FROM `login` 
                WHERE `username` = '".$u."'"; //needs to be concatenated

$result = mysql_query($sqlStremail, $db);
if(!$result) {
    echo "query failed:". mysql_error();
    exit;
}

$data = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {

    $data = $row;

}

echo $data['sponsor'];
echo $data['contact'];
echo $data['script'];
//etc
```